# SwiftUI Return View from Enum Type

Tags: swift, swiftui, enums

I am trying to return a view based on the enum but am getting this error:
`Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`

```
@ViewBuilder
func getDestination(presenting: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
    switch self {
    case .checkout:
        CheckOutView(presenting: presenting))
    case .shipping:
        ShippingView(presenting: presenting))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this error with the example code in Swift Playgrounds. Does the problem exist somewhere within CheckOutView or ShippingView? Also there should be only one parenthesis after presenting, i.e. CheckOutView(presenting: presenting).

Comment: Could you post what your `CheckOutView` and `ShippingView` look like?

Comment: this is a really bad idea. `@ViewBuilder` is designed to be used for body only.